# How can quantum probabilities be real in regard to what truly happens in an actual measurement?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Probability waves, amplitudes, whatever, in QM seem to return the chance of finding a particular outcome when measuring an observable (sorry if I am not using the right words).

However, when the measurement occurs, there is only one outcome. So, technically, or retrospectively, its probability of occurence is 1.0 (or 100% or whatever is used in this case).

I would believe the past has a probability of occurrence, as it already happened, of exactly 1. I am not sure anyone is arguing that the past is unsure and still variable (unlike its recollection).

So how can it be said that there was a lesser than 100% probability of this occurring?

Is this the probability of events that those probability waves refer to, or do they actually refer to the confidence level as in weather predictions?

In other terms, does QM theory state that reality could have been different than what it actually is?

I suspect the Everett/many world interpretation is comfortable answering yes to this.

Comment: I was going to write an answer but I think you are really hitting the two issues of [Measurement in quantum Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurement_in_quantum_mechanics) and [Interpretations of Quantum Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpretations_of_quantum_mechanics) which you can literally writes books on.  Personally I don't find interpretations at all useful in practice and a source of confusion for people starting to learn theory.

Comment: Ok, point taken.

Comment: @StephenG I agree that for beginners different interpretation my be confusing, but I think the statement that interpretations aren't at all useful in practice is up to debate and depends on what you mean by "useful" and "in practice"

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with QM. This is just a question about the meaning of probability. Perhaps this question should be closed as not relevant to a Physics forum?

Comment: Look at the probability of death within the year  by age taken from actual data  (2017) . Actual people died. Once they died the probability of being dead is 1, by definition of probability. Using this probability function as a template one can only predict the number of deaths, not the exact person.https://www.ssa.gov/oact/STATS/table4c6.html

Comment: @anna v: yet insurances will have other probabilities/statistics, that can tell the chance some customer will die sooner, ie. being a risk factor etc. How does it apply to QM?

Comment: probabilites are defined  the same whether the event is due to quantum mechanics, classical mechanics, or death rates.  *Mathematics The extent to which an event is likely to occur, measured by the ratio of the favourable cases to the whole number of cases possible*  https://www.lexico.com/definition/probability

Comment: But in general, the more you know about the system, the better the predictions.

Comment: Is it also worth remembering that probabilities such as this refer to the outcome of many experiments? If you toss a coin 100,000 times, then you will get roughly 50,000 heads and 50,000 tails. Likewise, if you set up a QM system the same way 100,000 times, then the results of your measurements will match up with the probabilities predicted by the wave function of the system. This is true regardless of the QM interpretation. A coin showing heads is showing heads. An electron with spin up has spin up. The wave function tells us what spin to expect the other 99,999 electrons to be in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you flip a coin, absent any other information, the probability of it landing on heads is $1/2$. But in reality, classical mechanics is (mostly) deterministic. In principle, if you keep track of all of the variables perfectly, you can determine on what side it will land.

Quantum mechanics is different in that it is impossible, even in principle, to predict the outcome to predict the outcome of some observations. If you prepare an electron in the spin state $\def\ket#1{\left|#1\right\rangle}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\ket{\uparrow}_z-\ket{\downarrow}_z\right)$, and then measure its spin along the $z$ axis, you will get spin up $50\%$ of the time and spin down $50\%$ of the time. And it is impossible to predict any better than that.

Independent of interpretation, there is no method the experimenter could have undertaken to the measurement that would have allowed them to predict the result.

Questions such as

> Does QM theory state that reality could have been different than what it actually is?

are dependent on interpretation. We only have one reality, so statements like this are non-falsifiable. In other words, this is a matter of philosophy, not science.

Comment: I like this answer. Tell me if I am wrong, but I take the fact it is impossible to predict the outcome as equivalent to a lack of information (even though the information does not exist at the time), ie. this is a confidence level type of probability. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You are mixing up two different kinds of probabilities. If you toss a coin, the probability of it being heads is $1/2$. If that has already happened, the probability that the outcome was heads is still $1/2$, but that's not what you are referring to. You are talking about the probability of the coin being heads *given that the outcome is heads*. It's a conditional probability with the condition being an outcome itself. It's no surprise that you get 1. This applies to any stocastic phenomenon, not just QM.

Comment: I disagree. The probability of said coin to fall a certain way is not 1/2, unless you have zero information regarding its fall. If you control the way the coin falls you can choose to make it fall a certain side (e.g. limit the number of flips). So the question remains as to whether probabilities in QM reflect a lack of information (confidence level).

Comment: It seems to me that you're looking for hidden variables theories, which attempt to retain determinism in QM. The answer I gave you was in the orthodox framework.

Comment: I am not looking for them. I am asking about terminology.

Comment: What do you mean? Terminology only makes sense inside a specific theory.